# Security - Checking if current user exists before executing code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

In one of my controllers I have this method:

```
  def method_name
    if current_user
      @model = Model.find(params[:id])
      if @model.destroy
        flash.alert = 'Model deleted successfully'
        redirect_to models_path
      end
    end
  end
```

I check if there is a current_user assigned by devise before giving the ability for the @model to be deleted. Is this safe and sufficient in terms of security?

What I really do is just checking if current_user exists. So is there a way that somebody can "trick" the system that current_user does exist and as a result be able to trigger the commands included in the method?

Comment: it's ok, but it'd better to use some kind of security system. I recommend Cancan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which allow you to do this easily

Comment: Devise's `current_user` method can be considered as secure (just sending a `user_id` in your session values would not work, token stuff and everything provided by Devise prevent from that to happen)

Comment: Special note* Cancan hasn't been updated for Rails 4.  There is a port called CanCanCan.  You can also just move to Pundit which is just based on ruby objects that represent policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a spectrum of answers in this.  But if you want the user to be logged in then just do this at the top of your controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

That is provided by devise and ensures that there is a logged in user before allowing any controller actions.

If you have simple authorization then yes, most likely though you are going to want to make sure that the user has the authorization to delete the object.  You can do that several ways.  My favorite one right now is the Pundit gem.

You could also just check that the user owns the object in order to be able to delete it.  That code would look something like this

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id)
if current_user.id == @model.user_id
  # Rest of your destroy code
end
```

Comment: That `if` statement is not necessary. You'd better do `@model = current_users.models.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @mischa, good input, when I work with authorization logic in controllers I prefer to spell it out a little more so that it is obvious what is happening.  It helps when I haven't looked at the code for 5 months.